# API Gateway Authorizer not work with the Cognito User Pool only in Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm implementing the Flutter app using the **Amplify Auth** to authorize users with the **Amazon Cognito User Pool**. In detail, I'm using the official [Authenticator](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/flutter/connected-components/authenticator) component and everything looks fine as I can sign up/in and user is created in Cognito User Pool as expected.

However, if I want to use the ID token to communicate with the **API Gateway** via its **Authorizer**, it doesn't work. I tested Authorizer with the fresh new ID tokens many times but it always result in 403 Unauthorized.

[image]

I'd been thinking I was making any misconfiguration on API Gateway Authorizer or/and Cognito User Pool (although user pool is made by amplify-cli automatically), but I tried the same Cognito User Pool in another iOS app (copying the `amplifyconfiguration.dart` to `amplifyconfiguration.json`) with the iOS's Amplify Authenticator framework and it worked! Testing on the same API Gateway Authorizer returns 200 for the ID token I got in the iOS app.

Given that it seems like there's a gap on behavior between iOS framework and Flutter component, but anybody has any idea?

FYI: This is how I retrieve the ID token in each platform.

###### Flutter

```dart
final cognitoPlugin = Amplify.Auth.getPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito.pluginKey);
final result = await cognitoPlugin.fetchAuthSession();
final idToken = result.userPoolTokensResult.value.idToken.raw;
```

###### iOS

```swift
let session = try await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()
guard let session = session as? AWSAuthCognitoSession else {
    fatalError()
}
switch session.userPoolTokensResult {
    case .success(let success):
        idToken = success.idToken
```

Comment: Sorry, it seems it was my fault. The ID token I copied from the Android Studio log console was not full. I inserted the breakpoint and copied it from the debug console, then it worked as expected. I'll close this question if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your token result should have 3 parts, `access_token`, `id_token`, and `refresh_token`.  You should pass the contents of the `access_token` in the `Authorization` header for the API Gateway to authenticate.

Comment: Thank you. I think that depends on the configuration and not in my case. As I mentioned iOS app gets 200 with the ID token.

Answer (score 0):

ID Token should never be used for accessing resources. You shall use Access Token instead.

Still, if you want to persist this way, here are some considerations:

- For a REST API using the Cognito Authorizer, you need to configure the Token Validation part of the authorizer by setting it to the `aud` value of the identity token (i.e. the Client ID of the requestor) as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html Note that if you don't do this, then the Cognito Authorizer will only accept Access Token as valid method and return a 403 for any request providing something else than an Access token, which is your case.

> Enter a regular expression in the Token validation field to validate the aud (audience) field of the identity token before the request is authorized with Amazon Cognito. Note that when using an access token this validation rejects the request due to the access token not containing the aud field.

- For an HTTP API, using a JWT authorizer you have to configure the JWT authorizer to validate the proper claims and values.